# Why not support add/addAll operations for the set returned from entrySet()?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

The `entrySet()` method returns `Set<Map.Entry<K,V>>` in HashMap/HashTable. Why the set does not support add/addAll operations, we know key and value entry?

I noticed the `java.util.Hashtable.EntrySet.add(Map.Entry<K, V> o)` implementation as follow in Jdk1.8:

```
private class EntrySet extends AbstractSet<Map.Entry<K,V>> {
    public boolean add(Map.Entry<K,V> o) {
        // MyNote: Call AbstractCollection<E>.add(E e) and 
        // throw UnsupportedOperationException
        return super.add(o);
    }
}
```

Why does not implement to support add operation like follow:

```
private class EntrySet extends AbstractSet<Map.Entry<K,V>> {
    /**
    * @return <tt>false</tt> if key has exists
    */
    public boolean add(Map.Entry<K,V> o) {
        V old = Hashtable.this.put(o.getKey(), o.getValue());
        return (null == old);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, precisely what JDK version are you looking at?  I don't see that in the code for JDK 1.8.0 u152.

Comment: What EntrySet class are you referring to? There are Mutliple classes with that name, eG: java.util.TreeMap.EntrySet, java.util.HashMap.EntrySet, java.util.EnumMap.EntrySet etc. pp

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS java.util.Hashtable.EntrySet

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I use JDK1.8.0_65. Sorry for the confusion, the source code   is `java.util.Hashtable.EntrySet.add(Map.Entry<K, V> o)`

Answer (score 0):

It is in accordance with Map.entrySet javadocs:

The set supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the Iterator.remove, Set.remove, removeAll, retainAll and clear operations. It does not support the add or addAll operations.

Comment: But why does not support add or addAll operations by design?

Comment: We can only guess because it is never explained, neither in API nor in Effective Java. Probably designers decided it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

One reason I can see is that EntrySet is not aware of what kind of collection it belongs to, therefor it does not know what kind of keys are allowed.

Comment: Why would it be *less* aware of this than the original map?